# Siblings with same attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div structure like

```
<div>
    <div class='class1'>contens</div>
    <div class='class2'>contens</div>
    <div class='class2'>contens</div>
    <div class='class2'>contens</div>
    <div class='class3'>contens</div>
    <div class='class2'>contens</div>
    <div class='class1'>contens</div>
</div>
```

Here I want to write a selector which will select all the div elements with class='class2', they should be adjacent to each other. i.e I should select only index 1,2,3 but not div index 5 since its not adjacent to group.

Please Help here.

Comment: You can't do this with a single selector. You have to filter the elements yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

```
var elems = $('.class2 + .class2').add( $('.class2 + .class2').prev() )
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/5JZWY/)

or caching the selector (with an argument to a IIFE)

```
var elems = (function(x) {return x.add( x.prev() )})($('.class2 + .class2'));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/5JZWY/2/)

Comment: I was going to write something with `.filter`, but this is more elegant :) Maybe explain what the `+` selector is?

Comment: @FelixKling - I though it looked pretty cool, but probably not very efficient using the adjacent sibling selector twice to get the first element

Comment: You can cache the selector though. Would be two statements then, but still shorter than any other solution.

Comment: There's times I wish there was a +5 button. This is it. Really clever approach

Comment: @FelixKling - There's always `var elems = (function(x) {return x.add( x.prev() )})($('.class2 + .class2'));`

Comment: Right... not as readable as `var $class2 = $('.class2 + .class2'); $class2 = $class2.add($class2.prev());` though :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution with [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

For example:

```
$('.class2').filter(function() {
    return $(this).prev('.class2').add($(this).next('.class2')).length > 0;
});
```

It filters out the elements that don't have a sibling with class `.class2`.